# font Family not working with Ajax HTML Editor

Tags: html, ajax, editor

font Family not working with Ajax HTML Editor.. i mean i wan to apply font tahoma in htmleditor as a default. it should show content with font tahoma default.

and also i want to know for alternate of this html editor.. i just want textarea which can read HTML nothing else..

Plz Help

thankss in advance

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to StackOverflow. You're definitely going to have to provide a lot more information to get some help, but the community here is amazing, so if you ask your question well you wont be disappointed with their answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to style a `textarea` the same as any other element:

```
textarea {
  font: 0.9em/1.1em Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: How to use CSS: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html Oldie but goodie